# How to redirect a visit to one domain from another, on same hosting account?

Tags: redirect, dns

I have a domain... let's say www.myOldDomain.com. It is currently running a site about local services near you.

I got a new domain (www.myNewDomain.com), it is also going to run a site about local services near you (albeit in a slightly different way). In fact, I want to totally replace www.myOldDomain.com with www.myNewDomain.com - on the same host using the same hosting account ( I don't want to pay for 2 accounts).

I want ANY traffic to www.myOldDomain.com/* to be redirected to www.myNewDomain.com/WelcomeOldDomainers

How would I go about doing that? Would I do it programmatically, or at DNS?

**Update:** This is on a Windows host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to send a HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

In ASP.NET you would set Response.Redirect("www.myNewDomain.com/WelcomeOldDomainers") 
in global.aspx

Comment: Is there a way in the Global ASAX of an ASP.NET MVC app to detect the domain name and redirect based on that?

Answer (score 1):

**Linux Hosting**

The best way is using a .htaccess file at the root of your website directory if you are under linux hosting :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myOldDomain\.com/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myNewDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

*Beware though :* this assumes the $1 part of your old domain is the same than your $1 of your new domain. And from reading your post I'm not sure this is the case.

.htaccess allows you to configure that in a very flexible way though.

Look on google for "URL Rewriting" and "htaccess redirection"

**Windows Hosting :** 
You can use the web.config file from your IIS 7 or superior :

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/

*Beware though Bis :* Be careful not to leave old pages SEO goes to waste and be sure to map the best you can old pages to new pages or you'll loose all the SEO juice you have been building for these old pages.

Comment: I've edited my answer to point you to the use of web.config file under IIS 7